# Why does this for loop work and the function doesn't?

Tags: python, function

Can anyone explain to me why this code works:

```
data = "8 (including George Blake, aged 69, and Robert Reynolds, aged 12)"
chars = "()[]?+"
for ch in chars:
    if ch in data:
        data = data.replace(ch,"")
print(data)
```

But when i try to create a function to do the same with this code, the output i get is None:

```
def clean(data):
    chars = "()[]?+"
    for ch in chars:
        if ch in data:
            data = data.replace(ch," ")
bob = "8 (including George Blake, aged 69, and Robert Reynolds, aged 12)"
print(bob)
output = clean(bob)
print(output)
```

Comment: Because your function `clean` doesn't contain a single statement because you are missing indentation. Furthermore your function,even if it were indented correctly, doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you pass data as a parameter to your function and declare `data = data.replace(ch, "")`, you are modifying the parameter, not the original data passed to the function.
You should try to `return data` at the end of your function and then assign its value to output, such as:

```
def clean(data):
    chars = "()[]?+"
    for ch in chars:
        if ch in data:
            data = data.replace(ch," ")
    return data

bob = "8 (including George Blake, aged 69, and Robert Reynolds, aged 12)"
print(bob)
output = clean(bob)
print(output)
```

Comment: This still doesn't fix the underlying issue that `clean()` is a function with no statements. Python is a whitespace-sensitive language.

Comment: The mistake is mine, it seems the copy paste I made from spyder removed the indents.  I will edit the post appropriately.  It was the return statemen that I was missing